# Entity Framework - convert LINQ method chain with SelectMany to query syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'd like to ask a following question.
I'm building a query which will return some details about stored email packages.

Relationships:
Packages 1-------N Addresses 1------N OutboundPackages

I would like to convert testOK query to expression syntax, specifically the following statement:

```
referenceGuids = pkg.PackageAddresses.SelectMany(s=>s.AddressOutboundPackages).Select(s=>s.Reference)
```

Complete example:

```cs
var test = (from stamp in IssuedStamps
            join pkg in Packages.Include(i=>i.PackageAddresses) on stamp.Id equals pkg.IssuedStampId
            join addr in Addresses on pkg.Id equals addr.Package_Id
            join outb in OutboundPackages on addr.Id equals outb.Address_Id
            where stamp.PortalUserId == "f31c2582-f663-4f2e-a9f7-d41ba138f86c" && stamp.Used

 //I'd like to convert the following SelectMany LINQ method chain expression to query syntax
 //let referenceGuids = pkg.PackageAddresses.SelectMany(s=>s.AddressOutboundPackages).Select(s=>s.Reference)                            
            select new 
            {
                StampId = stamp.Id,
                RecipientEmail = pkg.PackageAddresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == 1).EmailAddress,
                SenderEmail = pkg.PackageAddresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == 0).EmailAddress,                                   
                DateSent = pkg.ReceivedDate,
                Remarks = stamp.Description,
                Ref = referenceGuids,
                Subject = pkg.Subject,
                IsMassMailing = pkg.ProcessingPackageId == null || pkg.ProcessingPackageId == string.Empty
             } 
             ).ToList();


var testOK = (from stamp in IssuedStamps
              join pkg in Packages.Include(i=>i.PackageAddresses.Select(s=>s.AddressOutboundPackages)).Include(i=>i.PackageAddresses) on stamp.Id equals pkg.IssuedStampId

              where stamp.PortalUserId == "f31c2582-f663-4f2e-a9f7-d41ba138f86c" && stamp.Used       

              let referenceGuids = pkg.PackageAddresses.SelectMany(s=>s.AddressOutboundPackages).Select(s=>s.Reference)        

              select new 
              {                                    
                  StampId = stamp.Id,
                  RecipientEmail = pkg.PackageAddresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == 1).EmailAddress,
                  SenderEmail = pkg.PackageAddresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == 0).EmailAddress,

                   DateSent = pkg.ReceivedDate,
                   Remarks = stamp.Description,
                   Ref = pkg.PackageAddresses.SelectMany(s => s.AddressOutboundPackages).Select(s => s.Reference),
                   Subject = pkg.Subject,
                   IsMassMailing = pkg.ProcessingPackageId == null || pkg.ProcessingPackageId == string.Empty

               } 
               ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy.

```
referenceGuids = pkg.PackageAddresses
                 .SelectMany(s => s.AddressOutboundPackages)
                 .Select(s => s.Reference)
```

goes to

```
referenceGuids = (from pa in pkg.PackageAddresses
                  from aop in pa.AddressOutboundPackages
                  select aop.Reference)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was really simple. From a performance standpoint is in general my query OK or am I doing any rookie errors?